# Get keys of an array with variable name in bash

Tags: bash

In my bash script I have two arrays. Depending on some logic either one or another shall be used, so I'm getting the name of a required array in a variable `varName`. I can surely get the values of this array with the code below but is there a way to get it's keys? Tried several options but no luck.

```
declare -A foo=([a]=b [c]=d)
declare -A bar=([e]=f [g]=h)

varName=foo
varArray=$varName[@]
echo ${!varArray}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without resorting to `eval`, unfortunately. To be safe, make sure `varName` is *just* a single valid identifier.

```
[[ varName =~ ^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]+$ ]] && eval "echo \${!$varName[@]}"
```

`eval` is necessary to provide a second round of parsing and evaluation. In the first round, the shell performs the usual parameter expansion, resulting in the string `echo ${!foo[@]}` being passed as the single argument to `eval`. (In particular, the first dollar sign was escaped and so is passed literally; `$varName` is expanded to `foo`; and the quotes are removed as part of quote removal. `eval` then parses *that* string and evaluates it.

```
$ eval "echo \${!$varName[@]}"
#       echo  ${!foo     [@]}
#  The above is the argument that `eval` sees, after the shell
#  does the normal evaluation before calling `eval`. Parameter
#  expansion replaces $varName with foo and quote removal gets
#  rid of the backslash before `$` and the double quotes.
a c
```

---

If you are using `bash` 4.3 or later, you can use a nameref.

```
declare -n varName=foo
for key in "${!varName[@]}"; do
    echo "$key"
done
```

Comment: So the result of the evaluation will be a string, right? That means it can't be used for `for` loop, right? The option would be to then pass it through `IFS` or is there more elegant solution? Once again thank you.

Comment: Yes, it would be a single string, so keys that themselves contain whitespace will present a problem. I'm not sure I can think of a better solution in `bash` 4.2 or earlier. I just remembered that you can use a nameref in `bash` 4.3, if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

There is an IFS-safe method to get the keys (or values) of an array indirectly:

```
declare -a things=("an apple" "a banana")
declare -a tmp
arrayName=things
eval "tmp=(\"\${$arrayName[@]}\")"
# "${tmp[@]}" is now ("an apple" "a banana")
```